# NetworkOnMainThreadException in concatMap() with Retrofit 2 and RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

In my app I'm trying to use RxJava to react when the user search for a new movie and retrieve movie data from a webservice.
In order to do this I thought to use concatMap to concatenate the action of getting the new movie query to requesting the movie to the webservice.
Doing this I get a NetworkOnMainThread exception and I don't understand the reason..

```
 createSearchViewObservable(searchView)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<MoviesWrapper>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<MoviesWrapper> call(String title) {
                    RestMovieSource repo = new RestMovieSource();
                   return repo.searchMovieByTitle(title);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MoviesWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getCause().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MoviesWrapper moviesWrapper) {
                    for (Movie movie : moviesWrapper.getResults()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), movie.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET /3/search/movie?api_key=xxxx&query=Jurassic%20World HTTP/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

---

```
  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:184)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:153)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:95)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:180)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:223)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
      at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116)
      at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:111)
      at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
      at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8171)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:202)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:162)
      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I just realized that using return repo.searchMovieByTitle(title).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) in the concatMap() made the code work. Because I didn't find a good example with this, is it the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem defining subscribeOn and observeOn for the returning observable from the concatMap(). The subscribeOn/observeOn outside are specific only to the first observable from createSearchViewObservable(searchView).

```
 createSearchViewObservable(searchView)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<MoviesWrapper>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<MoviesWrapper> call(String title) {
                RestMovieSource repo = new RestMovieSource();
               return repo.searchMovieByTitle(title)
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Yest this works. Is anyone able to provide the exact changelog for this change? It used to work just fine with Retrofit 1...

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke `subscribeOn()` after `concatMap()`:

```
createSearchViewObservable(searchView)
        .concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<MoviesWrapper>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<MoviesWrapper> call(String title) {
                RestMovieSource repo = new RestMovieSource();
                return repo.searchMovieByTitle(title);
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<MoviesWrapper>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getCause().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(MoviesWrapper moviesWrapper) {
                for (Movie movie : moviesWrapper.getResults()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), movie.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work!  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. -> Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError -> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: maybe you need use `flatMap()` instead of `concatMap()`?

Comment: the difference between flatMap() and concatMap() is only the merge algorithm at the end. I suggest you to read this article to know about it http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Comment: I know, but i thought it helps.

Comment: it doesn't! the problem is with the thread where the subscriber is executed and flatMap doesn't change that. I added an answer with a solution that I found. I don't know if it is the best but it works.

Answer (score 0):

ConcatMap or flatMap will generate a new observable which obtains data form the older observable.
So you are setting schedulers to the older observable, not the new one.